# Decompiling EXE to ASM

Tags: assembly, antivirus, disassembly

I want to make a basic antivirus for my free time.
Basically I learned about the basic structure of the EXE(windows) file.
How do I extract the ASM code from the file and the PE header?

Comment: Why do you think, you need disassembler in antivirus??

Comment: So how will I detect the virus part? @zxcat how would you make it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use [objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) to decompile an exe into asm.  Be sure you select the binutils when installing cygwin.  After installing cygwin, you can run the following from a bash shell:

```
objdump -Slx yourpgm.exe
```

Comment: Yes, or run Linux on Virtual Machine and use objdump there. Sounds like a black humor ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some free distrubuted disassembler.for example: [ollydbg diassembler](http://www.ollydbg.de/disasm.zip).

note: there is only some MS-DOS stub executeable code in the PE header.

Comment: "there is only some MS-DOS stub executeable code in the PE header." And what if there isn't? You never know where virus will choose to hide, and headers are also loaded to memory, right?