# Disassembler program for x86 architecture

Tags: assembly, x86

I downloaded ollyDbg, but it seems to be that it doesn't have a disassembler integrated by default . Disasm.zip file on the [official web page](http://ollydbg.de)  contains only source code, but in order to compile it, we must install a lot of obsolete libraries (f.ex MSDOS's dir.h).

Therefore,I'm asking for the simplest way to translate from machine code(.exe) to x86 assembly language(.asm).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606202/decompiling-exe-to-asm They suggest cygwin and it seems to work

Comment: Cygwin is not a disassembler, dude, it's a POSIX "emulator" for Windows.

Comment: Look up [`BIEW/BEYE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beye).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about 'the simpliest way' [sic] but I highly recommend the [IDA Pro - Free Edition](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

ODA, the Online Disassembler,  is a free, web-based reverse engineering platform that supports x86 and many other architectures.  Check it out at www.onlinedisassembler.com

Answer (score 0):

For me best disassembler is ndisasm, which comes with [NASM assembler](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10.01/win32/).

Also OllyDbg indeed comes with a disassembler, that's why you can see assembly from an EXE... Otherwise it would be pretty much useless as debugger.

Comment: Really? I thought that this is only a  machine code with translated opcodes.

Comment: Well... that's assembly mate xD