# Convert exe files to ASM files in Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, exe

I just wanna convert .exe to .asm , so how can I accomplish this ?! 
It seems that it is available in [Decompiling EXE to ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606202/decompiling-exe-to-asm)
but it is for linux .

Comment: to some one who votes to close this: [questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers;" are on topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Questions about specific tools are on topic. Asking for a recommendation for one isn't. Taken from that same link (empahasis mine): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objdump` is included in gcc, and there are Windows ports for gcc like [MinGW-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). Just download it and use.

Alternatively install Cygwin, which is a Unix subsystem on Windows, and run objdump in it

Another tool is [Microsoft DUMPBIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177429) which is included in MS Visual Studio

Related: [How to use/install GNU binutils (objdump)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11054534/995714)

Comment: Also: http://www.agner.org/optimize#objconv is pretty nice. Yep, it's my opinion. :)

Comment: Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)